# Change text color of menu items, ONLY on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, textcolor

I have a site <kbd>[here](http://azeverything.com)</kbd>

At the top of the screen, you'll see a menu. Hover onto "Everything" and you'll see a sub-menu.

When you hover over an item, you'll see a dark grey background on each menu item. The text stays red, and I want the text to be white on hover.

**Here's what I have so far...**

```
#nv-tabs ul li ul li:hover {background: #252525!important; }
```

**It looks like the text color (on hover) should also be in this div id, so I've tried this...**

```
#nv-tabs ul li ul li:hover {background: #252525!important;color: #FFFFFF;}
```

**...but it's not working.**

Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
#nv-tabs ul#dyndropmenu.menu li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    color:white !important;
}
```

^ should make the text white on hover while the other texts stay red.

Comment: Didn't mine work ? You could have commented my answer to tell me :p

Comment: @Lyth your code works :)
it's just that you needed to add the !important rule to override `#nv-tabs a:hover { color: #d80000 !important; }`

Comment: Oops ! Ok. I'm not used to !important. I'll have to check this a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this `#nv-tabs ul li ul li:hover a {color: white !important;}`

Considering you said your code is not working... you may have something setting the color of the text of your `<a>` tags directly... that's why you possibly need to access directly your `<a>` tags to change their text color...

I can see this in your code :

```
#nv-tabs a { 
  color: #000000;
}
```

I think this is why you must access your `<a>` tags directly to change the color. If the color was set with `#nv-tabs ul li ul li` you could probably do `#nv-tabs ul li ul li:hover` to change it.

If someone can name this behaviour, I'd be pleased. I don't know how it is called, but I'm pretty sure that's how it works.